# creating complex table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

Can anyone help creating this table,I can't figure it out.

[image]

I tried this code but got some errors:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
something & \multicolumn{4}{ c| }{something} \\  \cline{2-5}
& $ t_{1} $‎ & $ t_{2} $‎ & ... & $ t_{n} $‎ \\  \hline
\multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{\multirow{‎d1} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 $ \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you attempted to do this yourself? If so please post any code you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

Your table is rather simple :-). I will assume, that the width of column is expected to be self adjusted to the widest content and that it should be centered. For cell which occupy tho rows in one column you can define by help of package `multirow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
    \hline
\begin{multicolumn{4}{c}{something} & \multirow{2}*{something}  \\
    \cline{1-4}    
A & B & C & D &           \\    \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & $d_1$     \\    \hline
  &   &   &   & $d_2$     \\
     \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

For meaning of table code please read some basic literature about LaTeX. For example "Not so short introduction to LaTeX ...` which is part of all LaTeX distribution.